# vba - dictionary and arrays

Tags: vba, excel

The idea here is that I am having a sheet with more than 80,000 rows and six different columns. what I care about is the 2 columns though. I want the vba to go through each row, get the source IP in column D , the middle part of column F , and the last word in the message box in column F after this "**`->`**" symbol. Then once it's done retrieving the values from all the rows, print the results in 4 columns on a new sheet.

NOTE that one IP address can be related with many different words.

What I am looking for, is the vba to return the source IP in one column, then the next column have the last word found in column F, then column c should have the middle part of column F and lastly the last column to have the number of times that the specific IP was found with the last word in column F

**This is how the table looks liked (Column B,C,D,E,F)(Rows 8=<):**
[image: this is how the table looks like]

**This is how I want the results to look like:**
[image: this is how I want the results to look like]

This what I have so far, thankfully I am able to get the source ip, last word of column F and the times it was related with that IP, but what I cannot figure out is how to make the array getting the middle part of column F, to be able and go through a loop to match its value with the ones stored in the dictionary in order to print it.

```
Sub timesofattackanddestination()

    Dim data As Variant, dic As Object, k As Long, ks As String, kss() As Variant

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        data = .Range("D8", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).Value2
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    i = Range("d8").End(xlDown).Row
    ReDim kss(i)

    For k = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        ks = Join(Array(data(k, 1), Split(data(k, 3) & "-> ", "-> ")(1)), ChrW(8203))
        kss(k) = Split(data(k, 3), "] ")(1)
        dic(ks) = dic(ks) + 1
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A2").Resize(dic.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys)
        .Range("d2").Resize(dic.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Items)
        .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=.Cells(2, "A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=ChrW(8203), _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
    End With

    For c = 1 To Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        For i = 1 To dic.Count
            If Range("A" & c + 1).Value = dic(i) Then
                Range("D" & c + 1).Value = kss(i)
            End If
        Next i
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: It will be easier for us if you include the column header in your screen clips.

Comment: I created a class that will make this a breeze. Here is my post on CodeReview.com: [IndexedArray Class: Uses a Dictionary Keys to Index a 2 Dimensional Array of Values](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197144/171419).  The post has a download link for the workbook.  Please do not post my code without references the link.